# Block facebook messenger and whatsApp on Dlink router

Tags: router, facebook-chat, whatsapp

I would like to block facebook messenger and whatsApp on my Dlink router DSL-2730U. I googled the same and tried some of the methods but not a single one worked. It's really important as I want to keep my children at bay from online stalkers.

Comment: How about not installing the apps in the first place?

Comment: What solutions have you tried?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a build-in URL Filter in that router.

I guess It didn't worked before because you didn't enter all the domains that the app uses.You need to block all of the following

```
www.facebook.com
orcart.facebook.com
fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net 
api.facebook.com
orcart.facebook.com
fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net
fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net
graph.facebook.com
```

BUT as you can see it even uses the default facebook url. So it will block no only messenger, but all connections to facebook.

As for whatsAPP you can use the official IP list to block it:

https://www.whatsapp.com/cidr.txt

Comment: I tried the above method though I had already added more URLs before but still users are able to access the facebook messenger .I guess its because the DLINK router is not able to block https url. This is the screenshot of my router http://postimg.org/image/dws2aqywj/

Answer (score -1):

ALLrighty then... this is from the facebook dev page :

```
whois -h whois.radb.net '!gAS32934'
```

execute it in terminal.

It will fetch the list of all IP's assigned to facebook by making a whois call.

Then simply block the IP's, not the domain names.

Regards